# XPages - presenting an application in multiple languages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus

I have an XPages application which is available in 4 languages. I would like that each user can choose the language in which the application is presented to him. What is the best way of doing this? It seems to me that I need to set a user specific parameter but am not sure how to go about this. At the moment I use a scope variable to determine which language the application is displayed in. This scope variable is server specific so all users see the application in the same language. Now I would like the application to be presented in the langauge chosen by each user (although all users are accessing the application on the same server). In Notes this was possible by writing a value to the user .ini file. Is there an XPages equivalent of this?

Comment: Tony, I would find the slides from a IBM Connect 2014 presentation given by Brad Balassatis and Kathy Brown on this very topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPages Toolkit project has an Language bean that gives the options to set a specific language to an application or let the user decide.

http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Toolkit

If you can't use the extension OSGI plugin checkout the java source on github
https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesToolkit

An implement what you need